# "ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found"

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot using discord.py although the bot will not output anything for the first command and says it is not found.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import config



intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("-----")
    print("Bot is online!")
    print("-----")




@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello, I am Synth. The bot for this server")

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

In the terminal after trying to type "!hello" on discord, the bot outputs:
"ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found"

I tried to change "bot" to "client" and removing the parentheses on @bot.command but it did nothing.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

you need to put name of command in @bot.command(name=<your command name here>)

```
@bot.command(name="hello")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello, I am Synth. The bot for this server")
```